# Mysql results into array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

How can i convert mysql results (from mysql_fetch_array) into such a form?

```
$some = array(
     "comments" => array(
         array( "text" => "hi", "id" => "1" ),
         array( "text" => "hi", "id" => "2" ),
         array( "text" => "hi", "id" => "3" ),
         array( "text" => "hi", "id" => "4" )
    )
);
```

while the db looks like:

comments

```
id  text
1   blabla bla
2   bla bla
```

i've tried to fetch the values with foreach/while and insert it into two arrays but no 
success...

```
$some = array(
    "comments" => array()
);

$q = $mysql->sf('*', TBL_QST);
foreach($mysql->fetch($q) as $row) {
    $some[] = $row;
    // $some["comments"][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code that didn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My print_r gives:

```
Array
(
    [comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => lorem ipsum
                    [id] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => lorem ipsum
                    [id] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => lorem ipsum
                    [id] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

And the php I did for it is:

```
$comments = array(
    'comments' => array()
    );

/* To simualate the loop */
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    array_push($comments['comments'], array(
        'text' => 'lorem ipsum',
        'id' => $i
        )
    );
}
```

I hope this will be to any help and that I didn't misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($dbc, DATABASE);

$query = "SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `comments`";
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);

$some = Array("comments" => Array());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($some['comments'], Array($row['id'], $row['text']));
}
```

Comment: you forgot to close the bracket...and there is no "comments" row in the array..so it doesn't work...i have already tried with push and adding the "comments" into array...still doesn't work

Comment: Oh, oops. Misread where you wanted the data. Let me edit my question accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, or use `MYSQL_ASSOC` as second argument of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$some['comments'][] = ...
```

inside a loop

Comment: what is "doesn't work"? show actual results given with this line (var_dump($some))

Comment: if i commented this (line), that means it doesn't work...i already checked this with var_dump and as i said it didn't give me the results i wanted...however the problem is solved so thanks...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an **[associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)**, and for this reason a special function has been already developed in PHP which is called [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

**Updated**

 
I am sorry, I understood you wrong. In this case you need this block of code below.

```
$sql="select id,text from comments";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$arr=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
     $arr[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'text'=>$row['text']);
}
$some=array('comments'=>$arr);
```

Comment: $qst = array(
    "questions" => array()
);


$q = $mysql->sf('*', TBL_QST);
foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($q) as $row) {
    $qst["questions"] = $row;
   // or
    $qst["questions"][] = $row;
}
doesn't work...

Comment: See the updated section of my answer. I tested that block of code and it works perfectly. Final result is the array $some.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with the same structure as the comments table:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `comments`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)) {$comments[intval($row[0])] = $row[1];}
```

The comments array is now structured:

```
comments[int `id`]=>`comment`
```

Then if you need `comments` in the "some" array:

```
$some['comments'] = $comments;
```