# how to fetch record from Mysql in PHP manually?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having table with two columns Symbol and weight. I am using this code

```
$table=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo count($table);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($table);
echo "</pre>";
```

Out of the Above Code is

```
4
Array
(
    [0] => x1
    [symbol] => x1
    [1] => 0.50
    [weight] => 0.50
)
```

My table contains 4 entries. But it is showing only one. i want to see all the entries, can you tell how to access them manually.
I know i can access them using.

```
while($table=mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
echo "<br/>".$table['symbol']."\t".$table['weight'];
}
```

But I want to do this manually. Because later i want to perform some manual operation on this array.

Content of my Table is

```
Symbol | Weight
    X1 | .50
    X2 | .25
    X3 | .20
    X4 | .10
```

By manually i mean, i will fetch the last two record without traversing the whole array(i.e with the help of while)
then add the weight of these last two records.

For Example : Here my table have 4 entries and last two records are X3 and X4 with weight .20 and .10. I will replace these two records with the new single records that is X33 with weight .30. and my new table will look like

```
Symbol | Weight
    X1 | .50
    X2 | .25
    X33| .30
```

Comment: By "manually" you mean you want to access each record by its "symbol"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql results into array (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984005/mysql-results-into-array-php)

Comment: Acutally, I need last two records of the table and add the weight of the last two records and store it in a separate variable.

Comment: Possible to provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: made changes in the question @Showdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, throw in a `WHERE` clause or do a loop until you get all the data and store it in your own array.

```
while($table=mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
    $data[]=$table;
}
```

With your array, you can then access it manually however you would like.

The best option is to use `mysqli` or `PDO` since `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed in the future.  I know mysqli result object has the `fetch_all` function to get an array of objects.